# Different approach of making linq query is giving different results

Tags: c#, linq

This query:

```
var s =
    from student in students
    group student by student.Year
    into studentGroup
    orderby studentGroup.Key
    select studentGroup;
```

Is sorting me groups by students`s year. The result is:

```
FirstYear
FirstYear
SecondYear
SecondYear
SecondYear
ThirdYear
ThirdYear
ThirdYear
FourthYear
FourthYear
FourthYear
```

I wanted to do same query using different linq approach:

```
var s = students
    .GroupBy(x => x.Year)
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(record => record.Year));
```

But in this case years are not sorted correctly. They are sorted in groups, but not overall. Thats what I am getting:

```
SecondYear
SecondYear
SecondYear
ThirdYear
ThirdYear
ThirdYear
FirstYear
FirstYear
FirstYear
FourthYear
FourthYear
FourthYear
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `OrderBy` between the `GroupBy` and the `Select`:

```
var s = students
        .GroupBy(x => x.Year)
        .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
        .Select(group => group);
```